MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventTarget memory leak detected in @aws-sdk/client-sqs
The package version am using is "@aws-sdk/client-sqs": "^3.377.0" and the Node version is 18.20.2. It was working two days before. Suddenly I got the below error in my pod and it's getting restarted frequently. How to resolve this issue?

(node:1) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventTarget memory leak detected. 11 abort listeners added to [AbortSignal]. Use events.setMaxListeners() to increase limit


i'm seeing this issue but specifically going from 3.577.0 to 3.600.0 and i'm seeing the same on both @aws-sdk/client-eventbridge and @aws-sdk/client-sqs which implies it's a dependency that's common to both of these. i can't see anything logged recently here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues but it's probably the place to log the issue.

I've possibly been able to resolve this by pinning the @smithy/node-http-handler package (which is used internally by @AWS-SDK) to version 3.0.1
With this, I have been able to upgrade the @AWS-SDK packages to version ^3.600.0. This is not a long-term solution but provides a bridging solution until the root cause is addressed.
So, in short, add the following to your dependencies in your package.json file:
"@smithy/node-http-handler": "3.0.1",

Note: After doing this, you will need to delete your package-lock.json file, or npm will install the version pinned in the lock file, which may not be the same as the version you have pinned in your package.json file.
I've deployed this change into our systems and will monitor memory usage over the next few days, but the warning no longer presents.
I hope this is helpful.

It looks this might be addressed soon via this pull request:
https://github.com/smithy-lang/smithy-typescript/pull/1331
